# Can't launch Android Studio 2.2 on Mac OS X(10.11)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have downloaded Android Studio 2.2 stable and run it for first time, it ask me  to setting first but i stop the process.After that i launch the 2.1 preview to exporting setting,then stop it. I launch 2.2 stable again, my tool bar looks like the program is going to start, but then quickly stops. I don't know what happens. I can run 2.2 stable first time but fail even thought restart computer. The jvm version is right. Now i can only run 2.1 preview version.Can anyone help me?